# Reading ViewData after changing the source from string to JsonResult type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewdata

**The below code has been refactored as:**

```
WorkItemModel model = new WorkItemModel();
ViewData["ServiceName"] = model.ServiceCatalogModels.First(s => s.Id == serviceId).Title;
```

**Refactored Code:**

```
ViewData["ServiceName"] = GetServiceName(serviceId);

public ActionResult GetServiceName(int serviceId)
{
    WorkItemModel model = new WorkItemModel();
    return Json(model.ServiceCatalogModels.First(s => s.Id == serviceId).Title);
}
```

**This is how the ServiceName ViewData is used in one of the views:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtServiceName" value="@(ViewData["ServiceName"])" />
```

After the refactoring, the service name is not captured correctly as it has been changed from string to JsonResult and is being is returned as "System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult" all the time.

Changing the return type on the refactored method as below should solve the issue:

```
public string GetServiceName(int serviceId)
{
    WorkItemModel model = new WorkItemModel();
    return model.ServiceCatalogModels.First(s => s.Id == serviceId).Title;
}
```

Is this the right way of fixing this or is there a way to fix this by keeping the return type as ActionResult and returning JsonResult?

Comment: Your "refactored" code doesn't make any sense. ViewData is used to pass additional data that does not exist in the model from Controller to the View. You don't assign a JsonResult to ViewData. I suggest that you read more about MVC before starting to develop applications.

Answer (score 0):

I would say changing GetServiceName to return a string is the correct solution.  There's really no reason to convert it to JSON, as MVC can easily handle passing a string (as well as much more complex types, of course) to your model.  JSON, in my opinion, should be used in MVC mostly for asynchronous calls that don't involve the model binder.

EDIT: Since you're passing this to your view using ViewData and not the actual model, you could (I think) call a json deserializer class in your view to get the value, but there's really no reason to do it this way.